# Best practice for writing to resource from two different processes in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, asynchronous

I have a general objective-c pattern/practice question relative to a problem I'm trying to solve with my app. I could not find a similar objective-c focused question/answer here, yet.

My app holds a mutable array of objects which I call "Records". The app gathers records and puts them into the that array in one of two ways:

1. It reads data from a SQLite database available locally within the App's sand box. The read is usually very fast.
2. It requests data asynchronously from a web service, waits for it to finish then parses the data. The read can be fast, but often it is not.

Sometimes the app reads from the database (1) and requests data from the web service (2) at essentially the same time. It is often the case that (1) will finish before (2) finishes and adding Records to the mutable array does not cause a conflict.

I am worried that at some point my SQLite read process will take a bit longer than expected and it will try to add objects to the mutable array at the exact same time the async request finishes and does the same; or vice-versa. These are edge cases that seem difficult to test for but that surely would make my app crash or at the very least cause issues with my array of records.

I should also point out that the Records are to be merged into the mutable array. For example: if (1) runs first and returns 10 records, then shortly after (2) finishes and returns 5 records, my mutable array will contain all 15 records. I'm combining the data rather than overwriting it.

What I want to know is:

- Is it safe for me to add objects to the same mutable array instance when the processes, either (1) or (2) finish?
- Is there a good pattern/practice to implement for this sort of processing in objective-c?
- Does this involve locking access to the mutable array so when (1) is adding objects to it (2) can't add any objects until (1) is done with it?

I appreciate any info you could share.

**[EDIT #1]**

For posterity, I found this URL to be a great help in understanding how to use NSOperations and an NSOperationQueue. It is a bit out of date, but works, none the less:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Also, It doesn't talk specifically about the problem I'm trying to solve, but the example it uses is practical and easy to understand.

**[EDIT #2]**

I've decided to go with the approach suggested by danh, where I'll read locally and as needed hit my web service after the local read finished (which should be fast anyway). Taht said, I'm going to try and avoid synchronization issues altogether. Why? Because Apple says so, here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW8

> **Avoid Synchronization Altogether**
>
> For any new projects you work on, and even for existing projects, designing your code and data structures to avoid the need for synchronization is the best possible solution. Although locks and other synchronization tools are useful, they do impact the performance of any application. And if the overall design causes high contention among specific resources, your threads could be waiting even longer.
>
> The best way to implement concurrency is to reduce the interactions and inter-dependencies between your concurrent tasks. If each task operates on its own private data set, it does not need to protect that data using locks. Even in situations where two tasks do share a common data set, you can look at ways of partitioning that set or providing each task with its own copy. Of course, copying data sets has its costs too, so you have to weigh those costs against the costs of synchronization before making your decision.

Comment: Have you taken a look at NSOperationQueue? I think this may be exactly what you need. You can do all processing in the background, then merge the results in the main thread to minimize multithreaded problems.

Comment: Good answers below.  Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSLock

Comment: @ReyGonzales I'll take a look. That looks like a viable approach, for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe for me to add objects to the same mutable array instance when the processes, either (1) or (2) finish?

Absolutely not.  NSArray, along with the rest of the collection classes, [are not synchronized](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW8).  You can use them in conjunction with some kind of lock when you add and remove objects, but that's definitely a lot slower than just making two arrays (one for each operation), and merging them when they both finish.

> Is there a good pattern/practice to implement for this sort of processing in objective-c?

Unfortunately, no.  The most you can come up with is tripping a Boolean, or incrementing an integer to a certain number in a common callback.  To see what I mean, here's a little pseudo-code:

```
- (void)someAsyncOpDidFinish:(NSSomeOperation*)op {
    finshedOperations++;
    if (finshedOperations == 2) {
       finshedOperations = 0;
       //Both are finished, process
    }
}
```

> Does this involve locking access to the mutable array so when (1) is adding objects to it (2) can't add any objects until (1) is done with it?

Yes, see above.

Comment: I'd like to avoid locking anything in my app, so I'll probably go with some combination of the suggested patterns, but I marked this as the answer because it provided input for all the questions asked.

Answer (score 2):

You should either lock around your array modifications, or schedule your modifications in the main thread. The SQL fetch is probably running in the main thread, so in your remote fetch code you could do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [myArray addObject: newThing];
}];
```

If you are adding a bunch of objects this will be slow since it is putting a new task on the scheduler for each record. You can bunch the records in a separate array in the thread and add the temp array using addObjectsFromArray: if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd be inclined to have a concurrent `NSOperationQueue` and add the two retrieval operations operations, one for the database operation, one for the network operation. I would then have a dedicated serial queue for adding the records to the `NSMutableArray`, which each of the two concurrent retrieval operations would use to add records to the mutable array. That way you have one queue for adding records, but being fed from the two retrieval operations running on the other, concurrent queue. If you need to know when the two concurrent retrieval operations are done, I'd add a third operation to that concurrent queue, set its dependencies to be the two retrieval operations, which would fire automatically when the two retrieval operations are done.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good suggestions above, consider not launching the GET and the sql concurrently.

```
[self doTheLocalLookupThen:^{
    // update the array and ui
    [self doTheServerGetThen:^{
        // update the array and ui
    }];
}];


- (void)doTheLocalLookupThen:(void (^)(void))completion {

    if ([self skipTheLocalLookup]) return completion();
    // do the local lookup, invoke completion
}

- (void)doTheServerGetThen:(void (^)(void))completion {

    if ([self skipTheServerGet]) return completion();
    // do the server get, invoke completion
}
```

Comment: I like this approach alot. Luckily I have the freedom to do this.

Comment: This approach seems to line up with Apple's recommendation to avoid synchronization whenever possible.